# Oracle programming interview ques

Tags: arrays, sorting

Given an array and a player. The player selects elements from array. If the player selects an item with value `i` then he/she cannot select item with value `i+1` or `i-1`. Find the maximum sum of value the player can select.

> **I/P**: 4 1 2 8, **O/P**: 14
>
> **I/P**: 9 7 4 5 6 1 2 3 8, **O/P**: 25

`My approach`:

**Step 1** - Sort the array in decreasing order O(nlogn)

8 4 2 1

**Step 2** - Traverse the sorted list O(n)

1. Choose 8
2. Choose 4 (because 4 is not 9 or 7)
3. Choose 2
4. Stop (As we cannot be able to choose 1)

Can it be done using some other approach (better than O(nlogn) )

Comment: How do you decide when some numbers are the same? For example: `4 9 9 9 4`. And what will your algorithm give for `1 19 20 19` ? Something tells be your algorithm is not correct.

Comment: I think this problem requires a dynamic programming solution.

Comment: @martijnn2008 Yeah, this can be done in O(n) using dynamic programming. There's a similar task on codeforces - [Boredom](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/455/A). Look for solutions there.

Comment: @JanezKuhar there is no solution at that link

Comment: @Atinesh Well you have to go under that contest [submissions](http://codeforces.com/contest/455/status/A) for the task.